# Conversion of a value in VB.Net into bit upon insertion to Sql Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

For `X` in the VB.Net code below, I need to pass in a bit value. what is the equivalent of a bit in VB.Net to make the conversion and insertion occur into the  Sql Server table

The `parmList_chg` is of type `String` because most of the values being passed in are of the `string` data type

```
Dim parmList_chg as List(Of String)

parmList_chg.Add(X) 'But value of true


strSQL2.Append("INSERT INTO tablename ")
        strSQL2.Append("(bitColumn")")
        strSQL2.Append(String.Format("VALUES ( Convert (bit, '{0}') )", parmList_chg.ToArray))
```

Comment: But what is the value of X?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this table:
[Mapping CLR Paramaters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work (at least the part that you showed) if you fix a couple of problems

- Initialize the `List(Of String)`
- Remove the double quote after the `(bitcolumn")`

Of course the value of X should be: "True", "False", "0" or a positive numeric value passed as string
(Lower case version works also)

```
Dim X = "True"
Dim parmList_chg as List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
parmList_chg.Add(X) 'But value of true
strSQL2.Append("INSERT INTO tablename ")
strSQL2.Append("(bitColumn)")
                         ^^^ quote removed ^^^

strSQL2.Append(String.Format("VALUES ( Convert (bit, '{0}') )", parmList_chg.ToArray))
```

The resulting string is

```
INSERT INTO tablename (bitColumn)VALUES ( Convert (bit, 'True') )
```

And this is a valid SQL